# Could not pass the form values to database using python as a backend language

Tags: python, database-connection

```
#!C:\Program Files\Python39\python.exe

print("Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n")
print()

import cgi


print("<h1><center>Welcome to Racebook</center></h1>")
print("<hr>")
print("<center><h3>Account Created Successfully</h3></center>")


form = cgi.FieldStorage()

username = form.getvalue("name")
useremail = form.getvalue("email")
userpassword = form.getvalue("password")


import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host = "localhost",
    user = "root",
    password = "",
    database = "userdetails"
    )

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

sql = "INSERT INTO register(Name,Email,Password) VALUES(%s,%s,%s)"
val = (username,useremail,userpassword)


mycursor.execute(sql,val)

mydb.commit()


mycursor.close()
mydb.close()
```

// so i don't know what is the problem with this python code, i have connected this page with my html index page which contains form data, but still cant pass values to database via py page.

so here i attached my html form, in which i have connected signup.py thorugh form action and post method.

index.html:

```
<body>
    <div class="box">
        <center><h3>Create New Account</h3></center>
        <form  class="form" action="signup.py" method="post" colspan="3">
            Name : <input type="text" name="name" autocomplete="off" placeholder="name" required>
            <br>
            <br>
            E-mail : <input type="email" name="email" required placeholder="email" autocomplete="off">
            <br>
            <br>
            Password : <input type="password" name="password" required placeholder="enter new password">
            <br>
        
            <input type="submit" name="signup" value="Create">
           
        </form>
        <label id="in"><a href="login.html">Already Have Account?</a></label>
        <a href="login.html">
            <button>Login</button>
          </a>

    </div>
<div>

</div>
```

and in apache httpd.config file :
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .pl .asp .py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try it with host as '127.0.0.1'?

Comment: i have been using localhost by xampp server. an its ip address is 127.0.0.1

Comment: In your code you write 'localhost' as your host. I believe it should be 127.0.0.1.

Comment: so did not working bro.changed localhost into 127.0.0.1

Comment: nothing worked bro. don't know what is the actual problem.